# Script ran from end-user to run addEditor() shows "you don't have permission to perform that action"

Tags: google-apps-script

I developed a script for our users. However, when I test it using the user account (e.g. tester@gmail.com), the permission error shows up but not for me--the owner of the script and sheet.

Is there something missing with my setup or code? **Pls let me know if you have alternatives too.**

**1. Error:**

```
You do not have permission to perform that action
```

**2. From the tester's account, this is the editor setting:**

[image]

**3. When running the code through these buttons:**

[image]

**4. And when trying to open Script Editor from the tester account, this is what shows up:**

[image]

**5. onEdit code worked flawlessly with other functions. But if I run the function with the script below and assign it to a button within the sheet, then the permission error shows up, just like in #3  above.**

### GOAL

My goal is to be able to run a much larger script *which modifies protected ranges/sheets using the user account.*

The code snippet below where the error occurs is used at the beginning of my larger code.

### CODE

This is where the error occurs, specifically at ***protection.addEditor(user)*** line.

Even when using *protection.remove()* is not permitted.

This code snippet is to add the current user as an editor so that the user can run the code that edits **PROTECTED RANGES/SHEETS**

```
const removeProtection = function(sheet, type, user, protectName){  
  console.log(`userEmail: ${user}`);
  if (user == 'owner@gmail.com'){
    console.log('Skipped remove protection for owner');
    return null;
  }

  let protections = new Array();
  if (type === 'RANGE'){
    protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  }
  else if (type === 'SHEET'){
    protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  }
  else if (type === 'BOTH'){
    let a = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    let b = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
    protections = [].concat(a, b);
  }

  //use to specify a specific protection description 
  let arrayLength = (!protectName) ? protections.length : protectName.length;

  //save protections to be copied for later
  let savedProtections = new Array(arrayLength);

  //for specific protection descriptions
  if (protectName && protectName.length > 0 && user != admin){
    let j=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      let protection = protections[i];
      if (protection.getDescription() == protectName[j]){  
        protection.addEditor(user);  
        savedProtections[j] = protection;
        j++;
      }      
    }
  }      
  else if(!protectName){  
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      let protection = protections[i];      
      if (!protection.isWarningOnly()){
        protection.addEditor(user);
      }
      savedProtections[i] = protection;
    }
  }
  console.log(`Saved protection count: ${savedProtections.length}`);
//returns an array of protections so we can remove the added user later on
return savedProtections;
}
```

Comment: So essentially the code is ran within the `onEdit` trigger? If so, what kind of trigger is this one - simple or installable?

Comment: @ale13 i wasn't clear regarding onEdit. What I meant by that is the scripts that run on the onEdit installable trigger were all working. But if I run the function as a container-bound script, where i assign the function to the button, then the script shows the permission error. The permission error also shows when I run it from an onOpen menu trigger. Also note that this function must be triggered manually by the button and not through onEdit

Answer (score 1):

**Even though you'd shared the spreadsheet with this user, this doesn't mean that they have access to the protection you have set in place.**

If they don't have permission to edit or access those protected ranges/sheets, they will also lack permission to edit the protections themselves.

It's also important to notice that the script inherits the permission from the user executing the script, therefore, what you are experiencing seems to be the expected behavior.

Regarding the `onOpen` simple trigger, it is important to note the following:

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

Therefore, since the `addEditor` requires authorization, you will have to use an installable trigger. However, be mindful of the following too:

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger, it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has edit access), but it runs as your account.

If you want to share the script with multiple users, the best solution in this case is to create an add-on as this will end up solving most authorization issues you seem to be running into at the moment.

#### Reference

- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Simple Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Extending Google Sheets with Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/sheets).